# Does this sentence require a comma somewhere?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, commas

> Mark Twain understood that lampooning a bad idea with humor was the
>   most effective criticism.

I just can't help but feel there's a comma in there somewhere, but I can't figure it out!!

Comment: Does *this sentence* does require a comma, somewhere? ;)

Comment: @New Alexandria: *That* sentence requires more drastic attention, somewhere else! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In clauses  with a long subject such as *lampooning a bad idea with humor*, we do sometimes make a mini-pause in speech before the verb, which is why some pople would place a comma after *humor*. However this would be incorrect. One of the few absolute rules of English punctuation is that we must not separate a verb from its subject by a single comma.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly where I was thinking of putting a comma.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to think about a comma is a pause.  Say the sentence out loud.  Do you pause?  If so, put in a comma.  If you don't, no comma needed.

Honestly, I wouldn't put a comma in that sentence.  There are no grammatical rules that require a comma, and I don't pause at all when saying it.

Comment: While there are no grammatical rules that require a comma, there are grammatical rules that forbid a comma – see the answer by [tunny](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/87018/tunny).

Comment: Actually, there are grammatical rules that require a comma. Lists come to mind, among many.